# Get Toner Level from printers via SNMP Batch

Tags: arrays, batch-file, snmp, oid

I was asked to write a program that asks all printers in the network about there Name, Location and CMYK Toners (How many percentages are left). So i started with the OID's and tried it for only one printer. This worked. Then i wrote a .bat file with all querys i had to do. I made an array for all 97 printers. As i would use the array in the Codeline nothing worked. In my opinion the Codeline doesn't accept the array. I googled for everything and tried everything but nothing worked so I wanted to ask you what my problem is. Also I want to write it out in an .txt file.

My Code:

```
@echo off

setlocal enableDelayedExpansion 

SET count=0

SET a[0]= 172.22.10.3
SET a[1]= 172.22.10.2
SET a[2]= 172.22.10.1
SET a[3]= 172.22.10.5

snmpwalk -v2c -c public %a[%count%]% 5 1.3.6.1.2.1.25.3.2.1.3.1
>>C:\Temp\Drucker.txt
//Printer Name

snmpwalk -v2c -c public %a[%count%]% 1.3.6.1.2.1.1.6 >>C:\Temp\Drucker.txt
//Printer Location

snmpwalk -v2c -c public %a[%count%]% 1.3.6.1.2.1.43.11.1.1.9.1.4
>>C:\Temp\Drucker.txt
//Black Toner   

snmpwalk -v2c -c public %a[%count%]% 1.3.6.1.2.1.43.11.1.1.9.1.1
>>C:\Temp\Drucker.txt
//Cyan Toner

snmpwalk -v2c -c public %a[%count%]% 1.3.6.1.2.1.43.11.1.1.9.1.2
>>C:\Temp\Drucker.txt
//Magenta Toner

snmpwalk -v2c -c public %a[%count%]% 1.3.6.1.2.1.43.11.1.1.9.1.3
>>C:\Temp\Drucker.txt
//Yellow Toner

endlocal
```

The Picture is showing the error message that comes when I start the .bat file.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the way you should iterate over an array:

```
@echo off 
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion 

set hosts[0]=172.22.10.3
set hosts[1]=172.22.10.2
set hosts[2]=172.22.10.1
set hosts[3]=172.22.10.5

for /l %%n in (0,1,3) do ( 
   echo !hosts[%%n]! 
)
```

The output looks like:

```
172.22.10.3
172.22.10.2
172.22.10.1
172.22.10.5
```

**UPDATE**: So you just put your snmpwalk calls into the loop like this:

```
for /l %%n in (0,1,3) do ( 
    echo Getting data from host: !hosts[%%n]! 

    echo Printer Name
    snmpwalk -v2c -c public !hosts[%%n]! 1.3.6.1.2.1.1.5
    echo Printer Location
    snmpwalk -v2c -c public !hosts[%%n]! 1.3.6.1.2.1.1.6 
    echo Black Toner   
    snmpwalk -v2c -c public !hosts[%%n]! 1.3.6.1.2.1.43.11.1.1.9.1.4 
    echo Cyan Toner      
    snmpwalk -v2c -c public !hosts[%%n]! 1.3.6.1.2.1.43.11.1.1.9.1.1
    echo Magenta Toner
    snmpwalk -v2c -c public !hosts[%%n]! 1.3.6.1.2.1.43.11.1.1.9.1.2
    echo Yellow Toner
    snmpwalk -v2c -c public !hosts[%%n]! 1.3.6.1.2.1.43.11.1.1.9.1.3
)
```

**IMPORTANT**: Consider using -Oqv option of snmpwalk to print values only.

Comment: Yeah i read this a lot of times but how am i supposed to fit it in the command to ask for the name or location ?

Comment: @Scarlet I've updated the answer to show you exactly how it is supposed to be done

Comment: @Scarlet I also suggest using 1.3.6.1.2.1.1.5 to get the name as it is more standard and defined in RFC1213.

Comment: @AndresKomiagin Thanks alot, you really made my day :). It works now. Just one little other question. Do you know how i can only get the numbers. Because when i know write it inti the .txt there is a the OID and some other words and at the end there is the number i need, ist there some easy way to only get the number ?

Comment: @Scarlet Use -Oqv option of snmpwalk. Put it right after public

Comment: Really big thanks, you really saved my internship. I struggeled at this point for over an week.

Comment: @Scarlet You're welcome. Don't forget to mark it as answer)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the expression `%a[%count%]%`, which is interpreted as a variable `%a[%` (empty) plus a literal string `count` plus a variable `%]%` (empty too).

A possible solution is:

```cmd
call snmpwalk -v2c -c public %%a[%count%]%% ...
```

Or you use [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html), which is faster and better in my opinion:

```cmd
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
rem ...
snmpwalk -v2c -c public !a[%count%]! ...
rem ...
endlocal
```

Or, to avoid `%`-expansion, use a `for` loop, like this:

```cmd
for %%C in (%count%) do (
    snmpwalk -v2c -c public !a[%%C]! ...
)
```

Comment: Ok I tried all three solutions and at the last one the program did not start at all, and at the first and second one i got an error.

The error says:
   ´No log handeling enabled - using stderr logging 

    snmp_build: unknown failuresnmpwalk:     Error building ASN.1
    representation (Can't build OID for variable )´

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know `snmpwalk` at all, and I have absolutely no clue what it does or how it works; I just pointed out pure `cmd`/batch variable expansion issues in my answer...